# Does Python have an equivaled of VBA 'Set' command? (short user defined reference to manipulate an object)

Tags: python, pandas

I have this line which changes the value of this cell to 5:

```py
df[header].at[row_num] = 5
```

I was wondering if there's a cleaner/shorter way to refer to `df[header].at[row_num]`?

in VBA there's a 'Set' command that does the same job but in an easier way:

```
# Note..this 'set' command is borrowed from VBA.
# This is not the python 'set' command that applies to sets like {1,2,3}
set my_cell = df[header].at[row_num]
my_cell = 5
```

In this example once I make that delcaration I don't need to write this long code `df[header].at[row_num]` anymore since I can just use `my_cell = 5` to be exactly equivalent to  `df[header].at[row_num] = 5`

Comment: I think you are talking about [indexing and selecting data in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html). You can explore `df.loc` and `df.iloc`

Comment: No, there isn't. Note that you should use `df.at[row_num, header]`

Comment: @SurajShourie No, thanks but that's not what I'm talking about

Comment: @Chadee I provided an answer to make it clear that it is not possible and give a attempt to explain why, and a potentially useful workaround. Let me know if this fits your use case (if not, please provide a more complete example of it)

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can't overload the `=`. It is not an operator.

You can create a proxy object that contains the dataframe and its indices and use `set()` and `get()` methods to modify the dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

class DFRef:
  def __init__(self, df, row, col) -> None:
    self.df = df
    self.row = row
    self.col = col
  def set(self, val):
    self.df.at[self.row, self.col] = val
  def get(self):
    return self.df.at[self.row, self.col]

data = [['Axel',32], ['Alice', 26], ['Anton', 45]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])

myrefName = DFRef(df, 1, 'Name')
myrefAge = DFRef(df, 1, 'Age')
myrefName.set('Audrie')
myrefAge.set(66)
print(myrefName.get())
print('=====')
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate the code but that's longer than the original code....I recon that the answer is no there's nothing in Python equivalent to VBA set and as such I'll just use the Pandas traditional way.

Comment: @ChadeeFouad if you only use the reference 1 time why create a reference

Comment: @ChadeeFouad if you could create a reference do you think that goes without any code, now the code is explicit and not part of a library

Comment: I'm not using it 1 time...maybe 3-4 times

Answer (score 1):

#### This is not possible, and not desirable.

An explanation for that lies in the difference between spreadsheets and pandas DataFrames.

In your spreadsheet program, you can reference a cell unambiguously, C3 in Sheet1 is always C3 in Sheet1.

In a pandas DataFrame, however, many operations return a copy of the input, which means that it now becomes ambiguous which "Cell" you would like to reference.

For example, **let's assume** that you could use `set my_cell = df.at[row_num, header]`:

```
set my_cell = df.at[row_num, header]
df_copy = df.copy()
df = df * 2
my_cell = 5
```

What should be updated here? the original object, still referenced by `df_copy`? or the new object that was reassigned to `df` in `df = df * 2`?

This ambiguity would make it more an issue and source of bugs than a helpful tool.

#### Workaround: dictionary of labels

If the real issue is that you don't want to update the indices in several locations of your code if those change, a workaround might be to use a dictionary of labels -> indices. Define the indices once and then use the label:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [4, 5, 6]
                  })

labels = {'my_cell': (0, 'A'), 'my_other_cell': (2, 'B')}

df.loc[labels['my_cell']] = 9


   A  B
0  9  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc`, it works same to your code.

```
row_num = 100
header = 'xxx'
df.loc[row_num, header] = 5
```

if you want to change values in `multiple rows` e.g. from 1 to 100:

```
df.loc[1:101, header] = 5
```

if you want to change values in `several columns` and all these columns value would be changed to 5, e.g 'col_1', 'col_2':

```
df.loc[:, ['col_1', 'col_2']] = 5
```

if you want to change values to 5 in `col_1` when they are equals to 4:

```
df.loc[df['col_1']==4, ['col_1']] = 5
```

Comment: the OP is not asking how to update a dataframe, he wants to update the same  dataframe location multiple times and prevent he makes typos by using a "reference"

Comment: @rioV8 Yes you're absolutely correct...I know how to update the df...I just was looking for a cleaner/shorter code